# what is $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \lceil x\rceil/x$?

Tags: calculus, limits

What is $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\lceil x \rceil}{x}$ ?  Here, $\lceil x \rceil$ is the ceiling function at $x$.

For left limit and right limit as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @eva You may want to pick an answer as best. Just click on the check mark on the answer.

Comment: You know, this question has made me acquire a deep irrational, $\pi$-like hatred for limits.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that [x] is the floor of x, then look at [this graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%5bx%5d+%3D%3D+Floor%5bx%5d%2Fx+).

Assuming that [x] is the ceiling of x, then look at [this similar looking graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%5bx%5d+%3D%3D+Ceiling%5bx%5d%2Fx+).

Assuming that [x] is the "nearest integer" function, then consider what the nearest integer is on the interval [-0.49, 0.49].

If this is something else, please specify.

Comment: [x] is the ceiling of x

Answer (score 8):

No need for graphs or WA.  Just note that

$$
\lceil x \rceil = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{cl}
 1 & x \in (0,1) \\
 0 & x \in (-1,0)
\end{array}
\right.$$

Hence, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\lceil x \rceil}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = + \infty$.  On the other hand, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\lceil x \rceil}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{0}{x} = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

What is the value of $\lceil x\rceil$ for small positive $x$? Think of $0<x<1$.

Answer (score -1):

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\lceil x \rceil}{x}$

[This is what the Alpha Wolf says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%28Ceiling%5bx%5d/x%29+as+x-%3E0):

> $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\lceil x \rceil}{x} = 0$
>
> $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\lceil x \rceil}{x} = \infty$

The two limits aren't equal. And what could this possible mean?

How did we get this? Look [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20%28Ceiling%5bx%5d%29%20as%20x-%3E0):

> $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^-} \lceil x \rceil = 0$
>
> $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \lceil x \rceil = 1$

And:

> $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^-} x = 0$
>
> $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} x = 0$

Comment: ⌈x⌉ is discontinuous at x = 0?

Comment: @M.S. And that means what...?

Comment: Surely you mean $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \lceil x \rceil = 1$ instead of $\infty$.

Comment: @Rahul Fixed - That's what happens when you translate from one "language" to another. :)

Comment: why is $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}\frac{\lceil x \rceil}{x} =0$? It is the ratio $\frac{0}{0}$, so it is undefined?

Comment: @sigma Look at the graph [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_{x+%5Cto+0^{-}}%5Cfrac{%5Clceil+x+%5Crceil}{x}) for a great intuitive explanation. $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \lceil x \rceil = 0$ because if $x = -0.001$, then $\lceil x \rceil = \lceil -0.001 \rceil = 0$ but $x = -0.001$, so $\frac{0}{-0.001} = 0$.

Comment: @sigma - When you get 0/0 from direct substitution when doing limits, it not undefined, it's indeterminate. The limit may still exist.

Answer (score -1):

The limit is equivalent to the derivative of the ceiling function at 0. The derivative of the ceiling function, by observing the graph, is constant when x is not an integer, and undefined when x is an integer. The above limit is therefore undefined.

Answer (score -1):

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\lceil x \rceil}{x} = \frac{\lim_{x \to 0^+}\;\lceil x \rceil}{\lim_{x \to 0^+} \;x} = \frac{1}{\lim_{x \to 0^+} \;x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1}x = \infty$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\lceil x \rceil}{x} = \frac{\lim_{x \to 0^-}\;\lceil x \rceil}{\lim_{x \to 0^-} \;x} = \frac{0}{\lim_{x \to 0^-} \;x} = \lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{0}x = 0$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\lceil x \rceil}{x} \not = \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\lceil x \rceil}{x} \therefore \;\, \not \exists \;\;\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\lceil x \rceil}{x}$$